# What is the time complexity of this implementation of Karger's Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, pseudocode

I was searching for implementation of Karger's Algorithms and found [this](https://www.scaler.com/topics/data-structures/kargers-algorithm-for-minimum-cut/):

```
 //Find, and Union are the use of Disjoint set union on the nodes.
 MinCut(edges, V, E):
     vertices=V
     While(vertices > 2):
         i=Random integer in the range [0,E-1]
         set_1=find(edges[i].u)
         set_2=find(edges[i].v)
         if(set_1 != set_2):
             vertices = vertices-1
             Union(u, v)
     ans=0
     For(i in the range 0 to E-1):
         set_1=find(edges[i].u)
         set_2=find(edges[i].v)
         if(set_1 != set_2):
             ans = ans + 1
     Return ans
```

Unlike other implementations I've seen online, this one doesn't involve adjacency matrices, self-loop removal etc.

While I understand how this works, I don't understand whether it'll be significantly slower than other implementations. We aren't removing any edges, so it seems there will be a lot of operations wasted on edges where `set_1 == set_2`.

The note at the end says that the time complexity for `MinCut` is `~O(E)`, but why does the while loop run for `O(E)` times? Can someone please elaborate on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't, in general. With n vertices, if we unite a path with n/2 vertices with a clique with n/2 vertices, then with high probability (1 − o(1)) there are Θ(n² log n) iterations. If we shuffled the edges and drew without duplicates, then yeah.